# Validate if date is before date of current date in sugarcrm?

Tags: sugarcrm

I have created date (calender) field in sugarcrm ie. From Date and To Date.

If user enters date before date of current date then I have to generate alert.

Example: if today date is 03-June-2015 if he picks 02-June-2015 or before 02 June then I have to generate alert.

Answer (score 1):

You need to call function check_start_date() onchange event of both the datepicker. i.e. startdate and enddate

```
function check_start_date() { 
    var startDate = $('#start_date').val();
    var endDate = $('#end_date').val(); 
    var startDateVal;
    var endDateVal; 
    /* check field must not be empty */
    if (startDate != '' || enddate != '') {
        startDateVal = Date.parse(startDate);
        endDateVal = Date.parse(endDate);
        if (endDateVal >= startDateVal ) {
            return true;
        } else {
            alert("End date should be greater than start date");
            return false;
        }
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Bro,  Thanks for your reply.
It's still not working.

step1: .js page
var startDate = $('#cycle_one_training_date1_c').val();
var endDate = $('#cycle_one_training_date2_c').val(); 

step2: added code in editviewdefs.php 

'displayParams' =>
            array(
                'field' =>
                array (
                    'onchange' => 'check_start_date();',
                ),
            ),

Comment: It's showing alert mes "End date should be greater than start date". but after I closed the popup still showing the past date.. it should be after the date...

Comment: You need to perform the action if condition will get true and false. like make the start date null something like this Or add one day into start date and update the endDate with the new one. Or else put your code here. I will suggest you.

Comment: `function check_start_date_three() { 
    var startDate = $('#cycle_three_training_date1_c').val();
    var endDate = $('#cycle_three_training_date2_c').val(); 
    var startDateVal;
    var endDateVal; 
    /* check field must not be empty */
    if (startDate != '' || enddate != '') {
        startDateVal = Date.parse(startDate);
        endDateVal = Date.parse(endDate);
        if (endDateVal >= startDateVal ) {
            return true;
        } else {
            alert("End date should be greater than start date");
            return false;        }
    } else {   return false;     }
}`

Comment: Thanks for you reply... I have pasted my code above.

Comment: Sachin Ingale, Can you please provide me the code. I am still waiting for your reply.